# What are the differences between Applescripts saved as *.scpt and *.applescript?

Tags: script, applescript, macos

It seems to me that those scripts that are saved as *.applescript are always meant to be the raw, uncompiled text while those that are saved as *.scpt can be either the raw text or the compiled program.

What advantages/disadvantages are there to using each extension?

An ancillary question: is there an analogous extension to *.applescript for the new JavaScript for Automation (JXA) language? Perhaps *.jxa?

Comment: May be of help, http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/146927/55365

Answer (score 6):

`.scpt` is in binary. `.applescript` is in text.

You can use Spotlight/Finder's find function to search for words in `.applescript`. You cannot do this with `.scpt`.

Since `.scpt` is already compiled, it's quicker to launch.

My favorite thing about `.applescript` is that I can write that a script that read/write onto itself, so that variables are saved for next run without creating a separate file to house the variables.

Comment: "Since `.scpt` is already compiled, it's quicker to launch" -- really? What's it compiled in to? Byte code? Has anyone ever done a study of run time differences between compiled AppleScript and non-compiled AppleScript on modern Apple hardware?

Comment: @IanC. I think bytecode